# pyserial write() writes only the first few bytes

Tags: python, serial-port, uart

I'm performing reads and writes with pyserial to a serial terminal running on a decawave DWM1001C. The serial connection goes from my Linux laptop to the device over a microUSB cable which also powers the device. The DWM1001C offers the serial connection internally on the chip. The connection is opened at the baudrate of 115200 with 8N1, as specified by the DWN1001C reference manual.

The problem I have is that when I call pyserial's `write()` on the serial device, I can only write a maximum of 7 characters per write call, sometimes as few as 4. Here's a minimal code to reproduce the issue:

```
import serial
import sys
import time

dev = "/dev/ttyACM0"
baudrate = 115200

try:
    ser = serial.Serial(dev, baudrate, timeout=3)
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed opening device: " + dev + ": " + str(e))
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    # Two CR's are required to open the terminal as the device default to "API" mode
    ser.write(b"\r\r")
    ser.flush()
    time.sleep(2)

    # only letters up to f are sent
    ser.write(b"abcdefg hijklmn opqrstu vwxyz\n")
    ser.flush()
    time.sleep(2)
except Exception as e:
    print("Failed writing instructions to device: " + str(e))
    sys.exit(1)

while True:
    try:
        line = ser.readline()
        if line == None:
            continue
    except Exception as e:
        print("Failed reading from serial: " + str(e))
        sys.exit(1)

    s = line.decode("utf-8")
    print("got data: " + s)
```

By using the `readline()` call and by monitoring the serial terminal over minicom, I have verified that only the 4-7 first characters appear in the terminal. Minicom can be used to interact with the serial terminal normally, so I assume minicom does something under the hood that this pyserial code doesn't.

I have a hacky workaround: Every time I perform writes, I split the input data into 4 character chunks and send them one-by-one over `write()`, then sleep for 0.1 seconds. This seems to work, but is likely about as platform specific as it can be.

The pyserial constructor takes a few different flow control flags and I tried setting each of them on independently. They are:

- `xonxoff=True`
- `rtscts=True`
- `dsrdtr=True`

They didn't seem to do anything. I also tried lowering the baudrate to 57600 to no effect.

What should I read on to understand what's going on?

Comment: Have you tried just removing the `timeout=3` when you open the serial port? Here's the [docs](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html) for pyserial. It says if timeout is set to None, which is the default, it would wait until all bytes are received. I would also make just 1 try block and have multiple excepts for the specific errors you are expecting. The doc says you would get a SerialException so you should just put that instead of the base Exception class for when it fails to open the device, for example

Comment: The `timeout` seems to be only for reading, and removing it does not seem to influence writing the data. With it removed I see the exact same outcome, except that the read hangs due to nothing being outputted in the terminal after the initial 4-7 characters. With minicom open at the same time I can verify that only part of the write() happens.